Off to the sky!
What bird is represented below?



I got something that looks like a duck am I way off?

@PDT Hmm a bit unsure if you got it right. The answer is not a duck though. You could rot13 what you got so far and I'll see if you're on the right track or not.

V tbg fbzrguvat gung ybbxf yvxr n qhpx’f urnq be n cgrebqnpgly sylvat va gur fxl.

Vg ybbxf yvxr n oveq’f urnq

@PDT Okay (didn't really think of that). I dont want to say too much but if you're sure you made sense of the left part of the image and how it should be interpreted then perhaps post a partial answer

Although I suspect, if that was the case (interpreted it correctly), you'd know what the answer should be

The bird represented here is a:

 KITE!

First, focus on the little bird icons. These are...

 ...encrypted characters in a cipher known as 'Birds on a Wire'. Each bird represents a different letter of the alphabet. In the given triangles, we have:

 Red: A-H-M-A
 Yellow: A-C-H-A
 Green: H-M-V-H
 Blue: C-H-V-C

 And after these we have a solitary line given by: V-CF

Now:

 Convert these letters into numbers based on their positions in the English alphabet:

 Red: 1-8-13-1
 Yellow: 1-3-8-1
 Green: 8-13-22-8
 Blue: 3-8-22-3
 Line: 22-36 - where we have interpreted the C as 3 and the F as 6 and concatenated them.

There are two interesting things to notice here:

 1. All triangles contain 4 numbers, the first and last of which are always the same. This suggests these numbers might represent a line being drawn between three distinct points, starting and ending at the same point, i.e. drawing out the triangle according to some numeric coordinates.

 2. The largest number here is 36, which corresponds to the number of dots in the accompanying lattice.

This suggests:

 We should draw these shapes on the grid. How? Well, how about numbering the dots starting from 1 in the top left corner, and proceeding along the rows and down? i.e. 1-6 on the top row of dots, 7-12 on the second, 13-18 on the third, all the way down to 31-36 on the last.

 If we do this, we see a shape emerge - it's a kite, the toy that one might fly on a string. And this shares its name with a type of bird, both things that fly 'off to the sky' as per the title and providing us with a nice linked answer!




Damn I did think of this but I got thrown off because I thought the image had to look like a bird.

This is it, good job!

Just wanted to add another thing to this answer: rot13(N xvgr vf n glcr bs dhnqevyngreny va trbzrgel, naq gur dhnqevyngreny qenja va guvf vzntr vf n xvgr ol gung qrsvavgvba.)
